# Barra de navegacion izquierda colapsable

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Que tal amigos,
Estoy buscando algún control que me permita realizar un menú izquierdo que se pueda colapsar como el siguiente ejemplo de este dashboard (obvio este esta en php y bootstraps pero quizá haya algún control en windowsforms):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html

Estoy trabajando con windowsforms en lenguaje c#

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Joel y bienvenido. Lo ideal sería que intentaras implementar tu mismo este control y si tienes dudas/problemas muestres tu CSS+HTML para poder ayudarte de manera específica.